# vim move position of the closing bracket

Tags: vim

Editing in Vim I often find myself in a situation where I want to move the position of a closing bracket.

e.g.
First i type

```
if a == 1 then
```

Then I realize I really wanted to have brackets around the 'a == 1' part so I go back and put a bracket in and end up with

```
if ()a == 1 then
```

I'm using auto-pairs plugin so the paired bracket is correctly generated.

My question is, what is the quickest way to get this to look like:

```
if (a == 1) then
```

For example currently I might

1. escape
2. use x to delete the second character
3. f1 to move to the 1
4. a to append and type ')'

It seems like there should be a way to

1. escape
2. move the second bracket a word forward.

Comment: `xf1p` will save you a little trouble.  I would strongly suggest you get out of the habit of being in input mode.  That is, rather than thinking of your first step being 'escape to normal mode', think of it as being normal to be in normal mode, and using i,I,a, or A to enter insert mode only to enter text, followed by <esc> to exit insert mode.

Comment: ack, i deleted the words 'normal mode' from the post. <esc>xf1p is marginally better but i'm looking to do less.

Comment: @evolution - Then make it a macro?

Comment: "move the second bracket a word forward.": That's just `xwp`.

Comment: I recommend surround plugin

Comment: yes - ok I think this is a matter of combining using xep (maybe as opposed to xwp since it gets me to the end of a word) and turning that into a macro. Thanks I'll do that. I guess I had the tools. i just felt it might be easier.

Answer (score 2):

With [lh--brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets), you would simply have to select `a == 1` and press `(`.

The *surround* plugin have similar mappings (they require several keys pressed, but they follow more the vim spirit).

If you really want to stay in insert mode, you can press `CTRL-V` twice, once before pressing `(`, then before `)`.

You can also select `a == 1`, and type `s(^R")`. (`^R` is for `CTRL-R`)